# How to calculate Percentage based on lookup list choice column?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Probably very  basic, but ....
Have a list with columnA = Gender and entry is either Male or Female (based on lookup list choice). I want to calculate the percentage of total number of Females to Males or vice versa. Formula for that please? Thanks!

Comment: calculate means for all list item available and then the percentage ?

Comment: Is your percentage column in ANOTHER LIST?

Comment: Thanks, all. Apologies for the truncated inquiry. Let me explain further:
In one list I have one column, [Gender] in which an option of either 'Male' or 'Female' is chosen. I want to total the number of males and females, then show the percentage of difference, e.g., 54% female, 46% male. All suggestions welcomed.